# Docusign /oauth/token endpoint return page instead of json with bearer C#

Tags: c#, docusignapi, oauth-2.0

I went through the OAuth2 proccess in DocuSign API, I follow all the steps using official docs, but when I tried to perform the request in order to get the the AccessToken I received an HTML as response, indicating something like "DocuSign is temporarily unavailable. Please try again momentarily." Although the http response is 200(OK), The weird stuff is when I test with the same values on Postman I get the correct response.

This is my code

```
public static DocuSignBearerToken GetBearerToken(string AccessCode, bool RefreshToken = false)
    {
        string AuthHeader = string.Format("{0}:{1}", DocuSignConfig.IntegratorKey, DocuSignConfig.SecretKey);
        var client = new RestClient("http://account-d.docusign.com");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(DocuSignConfig.IntegratorKey, DocuSignConfig.SecretKey);
        var request = new RestRequest("/oauth/token", Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic " + Base64Encode(AuthHeader));
        if(!RefreshToken)
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}", AccessCode), ParameterType.RequestBody);
        else
            request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", string.Format("grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={0}", AccessCode), ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        var responseString = response.Content;
        DocuSignBearerToken Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocuSignBearerToken>(responseString);

        return Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is awkward, reading the DocuSign docs they never specify if the authorization URL is http or https I assumed it was http, postman is smart enough to determine http or https when performs the request, my code doesn't, simply changing the Authorization URL from http:// to https:// solves the error.

Answer (score 0):

If your tests using Postman work, then there is a problem with your code.

We've all been there, including me!

In these cases, I send my request to [requestb.in](http://requestb.in/) to see what I'm *really* sending to the server. You'll find something is different from what you're sending via Postman.